# apache2 wont display a folder - while another folder works...confused

Tags: 13.10, permissions, apache2, php

I am on Ubuntu 13.10 PHP5 and am an intermediate PHP developer

Exact same file (1.php) in 2 diff folders - one works and the other doesnt...

```
http://localhost/vetpro2/1.php
```

The above works as intended...

```
http://localhost/vetpro/1.php
```

The latter gives error:

> "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /vetpro/1.php on this
>   server. Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80"

Web server is in `/var/www` and permissions are as follows:

```
aveesh@aveesh-asus-ubuntu:/var/www$ ls -l vetpro/1.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 aveesh www-data 1051 Nov 11 09:50 vetpro/1.php
aveesh@aveesh-asus-ubuntu:/var/www$ ls -l vetpro2/1.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 aveesh www-data 1051 Nov 11 09:50 vetpro2/1.php
```

Directory permissions are the same:

```
aveesh@aveesh-asus-ubuntu:/var/www$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x  5 aveesh   www-data    4096 Nov 11 17:27 vetpro
drwxr-xr-x  5 aveesh   www-data    4096 Nov 11 14:54 vetpro2
```

If, instead of `vetpro`, I use another folder - say `vetpro3` or `test` - everything works!

What can I do to get `vetpro`to work?

Comment: Do you have a **file** named vetpro in `/var/www` that might overshadow the folder?

Comment: Hi Pieter, I checked/doublechecked using ls -l and ls -al (I assume they show hidden files as well) - there is only 1 folder in blue called vetpro. No link names even....:-( So there is obviously something going on with the folder name "vetpro"...

Comment: I have deleted folder vetpro (and vetpro2) from /var/www using rm -rf and now ls-al vetpro says no file or directory. However http://localhost/vetpro still says forbidden as opposed to "not found" - for say something like http://localhost/doesnotexist...

Comment: it is working/fixed - i purged apache2 and started fresh - maybe some previous messed up conf files which i dont fully understand in sites-available default. Thx...

Answer (score 1):

it is working/fixed

i purged apache2 and started fresh
 maybe some previous messed up conf files which i dont fully understand in sites-available default.

To purge conf files, it is best to

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-common
```

rather than delete conf files manually